# High speed linear actuator/motor design

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, linear-motion

I need to make a linear actuator to compress a spring 80mm in 0.1 seconds. This is a speed of 1600mm/s. It takes around 15kg of force to compress the spring. How can I design a linear actuator for this. It needs to be compact as well, no more than 40mm wide or 90mm long.

If anyone can design a linear motor(e.g linear induction motor) to do the job that would be fine as well.

My budget is 40 dollars but the cheaper the better.

They seem cheap to 3d print, however, majority of the ones on YouTube are overly powerful and slow like this one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C9e--3nvro&pp=ygUWbWFraW5nIGxpbmVhciBhY3R1YXRvcg%3D%3D

Comment: Cross posted and answered: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/676956/152903

Comment: That one was a bit different. That was a design of a linear motor I came up with, here I am mainly talking about a ball-screw linear actuator that converts rotary to linear motion.

Comment: A solenoid is a linear motor for magnetized entities, and if you are hard pressed for space, it pays to get rid of all the excess (aka ball-screw - screws are a wedge wrapped around a shaft and wedges take up space, only giving you a conversion between force and distance at a cost of frictional losses)

Comment: Yeah. I initially wanted a solenoid, however everyone said that a solenoid would not be able to pull 15kg 80mm and told me to use linear actuator instead as they are quite powerful. However most that I have seen are able to pull over 100kg at very slow speeds whereas I want to pull 15kg at 1600mm/s